# PHP7 - Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property

Tags: php

I've been attempting to play with this dicecalculator found here: 
https://github.com/ringmaster/dicecalc

Previously everything functioned as expected, I could "roll" 3d6, 3d6+2, 1d12, etc without any problems.

After upgrading my vps to Ubuntu 16.04 with php7 on it, I started to receive the following error:

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: DiceCalc\CalcOperation::$operators in /public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php:34

I've done a few searches on *Access to undeclared static property* to no avail. I've tried returning static:: on each of them. Here's the CalcOperation.php it's referencing:

```
<?php
/**
 * Class CalcOperation
 *
 * @package DiceCalc
 * @author  Owen Winkler <epithet@gmail.com>
 * @license MIT http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 */
namespace DiceCalc;
class CalcOperation {
    /**
     * @param  string $operator
     * @param $operand2
     * @param $operand1
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function calc($operator, $operand1, $operand2) {
        $operators = array(
            '+' => 'add',
            '*' => 'multiply',
            '=' => 'equalto',
            '<' => 'lessthan',
            '>' => 'greaterthan',
            '^' => 'exponent',
            '/' => 'divide',
            '-' => 'subtract'
        );
        if (isset($operators[$operator])) {
            return self::$operators[$operator](self::reduce($operand1), self::reduce($operand2));
        }
        throw new \Exception('Unknown operator "' . $operator . '".');
    }
    /**
     * @param $operand
     *
     * @return number|string
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function reduce($operand) {
        if (is_numeric($operand)) {
            return $operand;
        } elseif ($operand instanceof Calc) {
            return $operand();
        }
        throw new \Exception('This is not a number');
    }
    /**
     * @param  number      $operand1
     * @param  number      $operand2
     *
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function add($operand1, $operand2) {
        return $operand1 + $operand2;
    }
    /**
     * @param  number      $operand1
     * @param  number      $operand2
     *
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function multiply($operand1, $operand2) {
        return $operand1 * $operand2;
    }
    /**
     * @param  number      $operand1
     * @param  number      $operand2
     *
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function subtract($operand1, $operand2) {
        return $operand1 - $operand2;
    }
    /**
     * @param  number    $operand1
     * @param  number    $operand2
     *
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function divide($operand1, $operand2) {
        return $operand1 / $operand2;
    }
    /**
     * @param  number      $operand1
     * @param  number      $operand2
     *
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function exponent($operand1, $operand2) {
        return pow($operand1, $operand2);
    }
    /**
     * @param  number $operand1
     * @param  number $operand2
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function greaterthan($operand1, $operand2) {
        return $operand1 > $operand2;
    }
    /**
     * @param  number $operand1
     * @param  number $operand2
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function lessthan($operand1, $operand2) {
        return ($operand1 < $operand2);
    }
    /**
     * @param  number $operand1
     * @param  number $operand2
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function equalto($operand1, $operand2) {
        return ($operand1 == $operand2);
    }
}
```

And here's the line that calls the class:

```
$stack[] = CalcOperation::calc($step, $r2, $r1);
```

I'm just beginning to wrap my head around classes etc so I'm not sure how to fix this. I've tried switching the return self:: to return static:: among a few other things I've found by searching on here. I'm just stuck now. Anyone able to help?

Comment: Seems self explanatory to me. Declare the `::$operators` array before trying to use it

Comment: I think you just want to use `$operators` not `self::$operators`. You could use `self::$operators` if you define them as a static property of the class, but currently you have them as a local variable in the method.

Comment: I tried adding `$operators = array();` on the line above `$operators=array(` and it still threw the error. Do I need to use the :: in front of it?

When removing the self:: part and using just $operators[$operator] I then get

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in /home/onemustfall/public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php`

Which the function is listed further down in the file

Comment: Thats the same issue except the opposite :) You are mixing up variables/functions and static class properties/methods

Comment: The second answer should be the accepted answer. While dan08's answer is correct in this special case, Will's answer is generally correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To define `$operators` as a static property of the class :

```
class CalcOperation {

    static $operators = array(
            '+' => 'add',
            '*' => 'multiply',
            '=' => 'equalto',
            '<' => 'lessthan',
            '>' => 'greaterthan',
            '^' => 'exponent',
            '/' => 'divide',
            '-' => 'subtract'
        );

 /**
     * @param  string $operator
     * @param $operand2
     * @param $operand1
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     * @return bool|number
     */
    public function calc($operator, $operand1, $operand2) {
...
}
...//rest of class...
```

Then access the `$operators` throughout your class using `self::$operators`

Comment: Do I remove the $operators array from the public function calc when adding it outside the function?

Comment: Sure. It will work either way, but of course the array is redundant (and useless) at that point

Comment: Making that change results in 

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Unknown operator "+". in /home/onemustfall/public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php:35`

If I make the change as in the answer of @will below, I get:

`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in /home/onemustfall/public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php:32`

The second change is closer, it's at least trying to call the add() function, but then it errors out. add() is included later in the file as a public function

Comment: Dude you also need to change to `self::$operators` in the `if` condition. (note the last line of my answer) Try to understand more about static classes. You are mixing up local variables and static properties in several places.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to change it in the if condition, you're absolutely right!

However now I get the same results as removing the self:: in the original code which is now: `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in /home/onemustfall/public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php`

Even though it is a public function in the class

Comment: To call a class method the syntax is `$this->add()` so `add()` won't work and will result in the error you get. Also there are limitation on calling instance variables in a static context, but that stuff always trips me up too.

Comment: Alright, well then I'm gonna have to dig deeper on this, marking yours as answer as it did solve the original question, but now I have to figure out where to change to the $this->add() instead of add()

Answer (score 11):

This is caused by a [change in the way PHP 7.0+ parses code](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect):

> Indirect access to variables, properties, and methods will now be evaluated **strictly in left-to-right order**, as opposed to the previous mix of special cases. The table below shows how the order of evaluation has changed.

[image]

Just change:

```
return self::$operators[$operator](self::reduce($operand1), self::reduce($operand2));
```

To:

```
return self::{$operators[$operator]}(self::reduce($operand1), self::reduce($operand2));
```

In PHP7, `self::$operators[$operator]` is interperated as "the `$operator` key of the `self::$operators` array" (which does not exist).

Comment: Making that change results in `mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function add() in /home/onemustfall/public_html/dice/src/DiceCalc/CalcOperation.php`

Comment: Moved the array back inside and changed to the above edit, still throws the undeclared static property error